# runtime error with params._source.field.contains()

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a query where I am looking for "machine learning" string in params._source.candidates.workExperiences.description field, but I am getting runtime error. I don't have access to enable Regex in the yaml file. Could anyone help me with this?

```
    query = {
         'query': {
                "nested": {
                    "path": "candidates.workExperiences",
                    "query": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": keywords,
                            "fields": ["candidates.workExperiences.description"],
                            "default_operator": "AND"
                        }
                    }
                }
        },
        "script_fields": {
            "recency": {
                "script": {
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "inline": """
                            def myString = "";
                            def isCurrent = 0;
                            def list = new ArrayList();
                            for(int i=0; i<params._source.candidates.workExperiences.size(); i++){
                                if (params._source.candidates.workExperiences[i].description.contains(params['search_keywords'])) {
                                    list.add(myString);
                                }

                            }
                            return list;
                            """,
                    "params": {
                        "search_keywords": "machine learning"
                    }


                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/sagarcherukuri/git_projects/project_development/experts_recommendation/elastic_search_experts_copy.py", line 143, in 
main()
File "/Users/sagarcherukuri/git_projects/project_development/experts_recommendation/elastic_search_experts_copy.py", line 132, in main
results = search(es_client, staging_index, query)
File "/Users/sagarcherukuri/git_projects/project_development/experts_recommendation/elastic_search_experts_copy.py", line 12, in search
response = es_client_name.search(index=index_name, body=(query))
File "/Users/sagarcherukuri/.local/share/virtualenvs/topic-modeling-DlV1fVLp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/utils.py", line 347, in _wrapped
return func(*args, params=params, headers=headers, **kwargs)
File "/Users/sagarcherukuri/.local/share/virtualenvs/topic-modeling-DlV1fVLp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/client/**init**.py", line 1830, in search
return self.transport.perform_request(
File "/Users/sagarcherukuri/.local/share/virtualenvs/topic-modeling-DlV1fVLp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 466, in perform_request
raise e
File "/Users/sagarcherukuri/.local/share/virtualenvs/topic-modeling-DlV1fVLp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/transport.py", line 427, in perform_request
status, headers_response, data = connection.perform_request(
File "/Users/sagarcherukuri/.local/share/virtualenvs/topic-modeling-DlV1fVLp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/http_urllib3.py", line 291, in perform_request
self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
File "/Users/sagarcherukuri/.local/share/virtualenvs/topic-modeling-DlV1fVLp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/elasticsearch/connection/base.py", line 328, in _raise_error
raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'search_phase_execution_exception', 'runtime error')

Comment: Can you show the error you get?

Comment: I am calling this query in python, shall I show that error?

Comment: I'd like to see the error you get in the ES server logs

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have access to ES server

Comment: Ok, then at least share the error you get in your python log

Comment: @val I have shared the error which shows up in python

Comment: `search_phase_execution_exception` we really need to see the ES logs, otherwise we have no clue

Comment: @Val, is it possible to check if a string contains word like this params._source.field1.field2[i].field3.contains('sample word')?

Comment: You can run Elasticsearch + Kibana on your machine and create a small test index with a single doc, then run your query against that doc and see the logs.